# Highcharts Dynamic Updated Highstock Charts doesn't display along with Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am a beginner in JQuery and Highcharts. I am following Highchart's highstock demo to create a basic html page to display Highstock's Dynamically Updated Charts. 
I started out with a bar chart and it works, but when I add a Highstock chart, it doesn't work anymore. 
I really can't figure out why. Please help. Thank you!

This simple bar chart works!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Index - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script>$(function () {
    $('#bar').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });
});</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="bar" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Then Adding Dynamic Updated Script to head:

```
$(function() {

    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global : {
            useUTC : false
        }
    });

    // Create the chart
    $('#realtime').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart : {
            events : {
                load : function() {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{
                count: 1,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '1M'
            }, {
                count: 5,
                type: 'minute',
                text: '5M'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected: 0
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Live random data'
        },

        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'Random data',
            data : (function() {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                for( i = -999; i <= 0; i++) {
                    data.push([
                        time + i * 1000,
                        Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                    ]);
                }
                return data;
            })()
        }]
    });

});
```

and this Div to Body:

```
<div id="realtime" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
```

And it STOPS working, as shown below:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Index - My ASP.NET Application</title>
        <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
        <script>
    $(function() {

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global : {
                useUTC : false
            }
        });

        // Create the chart
        $('#realtime').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart : {
                events : {
                    load : function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                buttons: [{
                    count: 1,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '1M'
                }, {
                    count: 5,
                    type: 'minute',
                    text: '5M'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                inputEnabled: false,
                selected: 0
            },

            title : {
                text : 'Live random data'
            },

            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'Random data',
                data : (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [], time = (new Date()).getTime(), i;

                    for( i = -999; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push([
                            time + i * 1000,
                            Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
                        ]);
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });

    });
    </script>
        <script>$(function () {
        $('#bar').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit eaten'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [1, 0, 4]
            }, {
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 7, 3]
            }]
        });
    });</script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="bar" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    <div id="realtime" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Please Help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you need to only include highstock.js or highcharts.js. I would say only include highstock as it includes all highcharts types as well.